# Import channel list via web on Samsung TV

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, television, tizen-web-app

I'm developing an app for Tizen OS and I'm wrapping my head around the channel list.

I've found [here in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdZ0IDwxBU0) a method to import the channel list via USB.
Is there a way to import the channel list via web instead? The process flow should be:

1. The TV download the file from a URL
2. The TV update the channel list based on the file downloaded

I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically, but some GUI-based method is okay too.

Thanks to anybody who can help me in some way!

Comment: It is not supported feature both API and GUI-based method.

Comment: Hi @LunchBasketball, thank you for the reply. For now I've downloaded the channel list from my server and I'm trying to iterate with a loop on every channel, using directTune api on each. Is there a way to "save" a channel on a specific channel number after I tuned it?